# Change registry url in gradle node plugin

Tags: gradle, npm, gradle-node-plugin

I am using gradle with gradle-node-plugin. The problem is that I don't have access to public registers so node cannot download anything from https://registry.npmjs.org/. I need to use nexus as proxy butt don't know how to change url to which npm is pointing. Does anyone know the solution?

Comment: Maybe you can create a task that runs `npm config set registry ...` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the Gradle Node Plugin executes `npm` itself to resolve modules so just updating your `.npmrc` with `registry=https://npm.yourcompany.com` ought to work.

Note that this is basically what `npm config set registry` does, as RaGe suggested in his comment.

Comment: where should the npmrc be in relation to the project or build for the gradle node plugin's npm to utilize it?

Comment: IIRC it should be a sibling to `package.json`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this directly in a gradle task you can use the following:

```
task setregistry(type: NpmTask) {
  args = ['config', 'set', 'registry', 'https://npm.registry.company.com']
}
```

You can also do this if you want to set the registry for a specific scope:

```
task setregistry(type: NpmTask) {
  args = ['config', 'set', '@scope:registry', 'https://npm.registry.company.com']
}
```